# Let $U\subseteq X$ be open and $S\subseteq X$ a set such that $S\cap U$ is closed in $U$. Does $\bar{S}\cap U=S\cap U$?

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X$ be a topological space. Suppose $U\subseteq X$ is an open set, and $S\subseteq X$ is any set such that $S\cap U$ is closed in $U$. Does it follow that
>   $$\bar{S}\cap U=S\cap U?$$

It seems true, but from what I know, the closure of $S\cap U$ in $U$ is
$$\overline{S\cap U}\cap U$$
and from this we can only say that
$$\overline{S\cap U}\cap U=S\cap U.$$
So do we have
$$\overline{S\cap U}\cap U=\bar{S}\cap U?$$
Perhaps this is true for any set $S$ and open set $U$, but I cannot prove it...

Comment: For a similar idea see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/197672/locally-closed-subset-equivalence-proof-using-barl-cap-v-l-cap-v

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement is true. Write $S=S_0\cup S_1$ where $S_0\subseteq U$ and $S_1\subseteq U^c$. Then, we are given that $S_0$ is closed in $U$, i.e.
$$\bar{S}_0\cap U=S_0.$$
Now, $S_1\subseteq U^c$ implies that $\bar{S}_1\subseteq \overline{U^c}=U^c$ since $U$ is open. Hence,
$$\bar{S}\cap U=(\bar{S}_0\cup\bar{S}_1)\cap U=\bar{S}_0\cap U=S_0=S\cap U.$$